# I have an issue, following code is not working in Internet Explorer 6/7/10:

Tags: wordpress

My jplayer is not working on ie7/8/10, first it gives me syntax error to Jplayer.swf i soved this problem,now IE shows the message like "To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your Flash plugin. " I am not getting what is happining, can anyone help me?

here is my code:-

```
new jPlayerPlaylist({               

                                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
                            },                          
                            [
                                    {                                               
                                            title:"credit",
                                            mp3: "<?php echo home_url('/audio/'.$_COOKIE['gita_language'].'/credit.mp3'); ?>"                               

                                    }  ]                                
                            , {                             
                                playlistOptions: {
                                    loopOnPrevious: true,
                                    autoPlay: true
                                },
                                   loop: true,
                                    /*swfPath: "js",*/
                                    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.0.0/js/Jplayer.swf",                                     
                                    supplied: "mp3, ogg, wav",
                                    wmode: "window",
                                    smoothPlayBar: true,
                                    keyEnabled: true,
                                    solution: "html,flash"
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a
>   recent version or update your Flash plugin.

Did you try updating the Flash plugin in your browser? And unless you have a specific need to support them you would do well to forget about making it work in IE6 or 7, and possibly even IE8.

Answer (score 0):

try to update new flash player plugin that will make the magic to work